# How do you Counter Values in two different Multidimensional Dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I do not understand how you are supposed to reference nested dictionaries in a multidimensional dictionary. I'm trying to combine the values of physA and physD from both the dictionaries into a new total dictionary, but do not know what to do for it to work. Could someone please help me by telling me how to Counter nested Values?

```
    from collections import Counter

    bronzeSword = {"Bronze Sword":Counter({"physA":4,"physD":1})}
    ironSword = {"Iron Sword":Counter({"physA":5,"physD":2})}

    total = bronzeSword + ironSword

    print("Physical Attack:",total["physA"],"Physical Defence:",total["physD"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it hit me right after I posted the question.

```
    from collections import Counter

    bronzeSword = {"Bronze Sword":Counter({"physA":4,"physD":1})}
    ironSword = {"Iron Sword":Counter({"physA":5,"physD":2,"magD":-1})}

    total = bronzeSword["Bronze Sword"] + ironSword["Iron Sword"]

    print("Physical Attack:",total["physA"],"Physical Defence:",total["physD"])
```